# Importing problem with urllib3 for webscraping exercise

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib3

I'm doing some webscraping exercises using Python and I've come up with errors in my code. Kindly need your help with analyzing the problem to my code.

I've already installed urllib3 using `pip install urllib3`

```
import urllib3 import urllib3.request

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def make_soup(url):
    thepage = url.request.urlopen(url)
    soup =BeautifulSoup (thepage, "html.parser")
    return soup

soup = make_soup ("https://edition.cnn.com/world")
```

Here are the errors I'm receiving:
Errors on lines 10 and 6

> AttributError: 'str' object has no attribute 'request'

Answer (score 1):

This is how it works when you are using `urllib3`:

```
Import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://edition.cnn.com/world'

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
response = http.request('GET', url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data)
```

For more info. on the same please see [documentation](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)